# Print a Python variable in hexadecimal by default

Tags: python, formatting

I wish to display some variables, data members in hexadecimal format any time they are printed.

My current approach is to define a class Hex:

```
class Hex:
    """Facilitate printing an integer in hexadecimal format."""
    def __init__(self, data):
        if not isinstance(data, int):
            raise ValueError("Hex expects an integer.")
        self._data = data
    def __repr__(self):
        return hex(self._data)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._data == other
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self._data < other
    def __le__(self, other):
        return self._data <= other
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self._data > other
    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self._data >= other
    def __add__(self, right):
        return self._data + right
    def __radd__(self, left):
        return self._data + left
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._data)
```

This works all right as the following examples demonstrate it:

```
address = Hex(0xdeadbeef)
record1 = {'address': address, 'counter': 42}
print(record1)
{'address': 0xdeadbeef, 'counter': 42}
```

The `__hash__` is defined so that the object is hashable and can be used as a key in a dict:

```
record2 = {address: 'address'}
print(record2)
{0xdeadbeef: 'address'}
```

The equality and comparisons are defined so that handling of duplicates and sorting works:

```
list1 = [Hex(0xff), 15, 23, Hex(0xf), 255]
print(list1)
[0xff, 15, 23, 0xf, 255]
print(set(list1))
{15, 23, 0xff}
list1.sort()
print(list1)
[15, 0xf, 23, 0xff, 255]
```

The `__add__` and `__radd__` are defined so that pointer arithmetic is supported:

```
new_address = Hex(record1['address'] + 0x20400000)
print(new_address)
0xfeedbeef

address += 0x3f00
address += Hex(0xfe)
print(address)
0xdeadfeed
```

And now to the questions.

Is there a built in or existing hex integer that somehow has its own `__repr__` attached that prints it in hex, but otherwise it would work as an int. I could not find such hence the above class.

The above pointer arithmetic works (subtraction, negation can be added similarly) and I was surprised that += works as well. Should I still add `__iadd__`?

Should I add/override `__new__`? Something like the following would not create duplicate instances for the same value:

```
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    if not hasattr(cls, 'instances'):
        cls.instances = {}
    data = args[1]
    if data in cls.instances:
        return cls.instances[data]
    # Create if not found:
    inst = super(Hex, cls).__new__(cls) #, *args, **kwargs)
    cls.instances[data] = inst
    return inst
```

Any other suggestion to fix the class Hex or make it better?

Comment: I'm also surprised `+=` works. `address += Hex(0xfe)` doesn't get the specified results.

Comment: " I could not find such hence the above class." you can just *define* your own, `class Hex(int): ...` then simply implement `__repr__` the way you did above

Comment: `a = Hex(0xf); a += Hex(0x1); a` prints `16`. When I tried to overwrite `__add__` I  got an infinite loop until I figured that `__add__` should return: `Hex(int(self) + other)`

To @Bharel: There are two additions, 0xef00 and 0xfe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a new class from scratch that holds an int (`_data`), why don't you simply inherit from int and override the `__repr__` method?

I wouldn't go as far as optimizing for duplicated values.

```
class Hex(int):
    def __repr__(self):
        return hex(self)
```

Edit -

Override the methods that return a new int with a call to super() and return as a Hex object. For example -

```
def __add__(self, val):
    return Hex(super().__add__(val))
```

Looks a little verbose but it works. Plus you can write a monkey patcher that takes a list of all the operations you want to override -

```
ops = ['__add__', '__sub__', '__mul__']

def monkey_patch(operation: str):
    """
    wraps Hex() around int's magic 
    method for provided operation.
    """
    old_op = getattr(int, operation)
    new_op = lambda self, val : Hex(old_op(self, val))
    setattr(Hex, operation, new_op)

for op in ops:
    monkey_patch(op)
```

[full code](https://gist.github.com/mentix02/243c7b1f2102f1375c577c943a2a2045)

This works -

```
>>> a = Hex(0xf)
>>> a += 1
>>> a
0x10
>>> a -= 1
>>> a
0xf
>>> a * 2
0x1e
```

Comment: I tried something like this and it did not work in some instance.  Now, I can only find the following problem: `a = Hex(0xf); a += Hex(0x1); a` prints `16`.  I tried to fix that, but could not immediately do so.

Comment: I think then the best way to go would be to override all magic methods you'd use with a super call to the base implementation. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about inheriting from int?

```
>>> class Hex(int):
...  def __repr__(self):
...    return hex(self)
...
>>> a = Hex(123)
>>> a
0x7b
>>> a = Hex(16)
>>> a
0x10
>>> Hex(a + 2)
0x12
```

Comment: `a = Hex(0xf); a += Hex(0x1); a` prints `16`